# is it possible to put a direct link in particular js?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I've been trying all day to get this simple light box to show the next and previous links. I want to try to put a direct link to the image file path to substitute it linking to a `#` and pulling the file path from the css.

I'm new at js, what would be the proper syntax for this?

```
Builder.node('a',{id:'prevLink', href: '#' }),
Builder.node('a',{id:'nextLink', href: '#' })
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question. A "next" or "previous" link would ostensibly show the next or previous image, right? What does that have to do with creating a direct link to the image file path, and what is "div #"?

Comment: My bad on the '#div'. I didn't mean to put that there. Those two id's are linked to a the rest of the portion of the script that reads the css for those ids. Right now the links tot the images are in the css and I want to put them where the '#' is.

Comment: I think there should be a rule on here where if you -1 something you have to explain yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the -1 is from what seems like a poorly formed question.  There is some code, but not enough to help those you're asking for help to work with.  Imagine what information you would want available to you when attempting to solve a problem, usually the more pieces you can provide the better the community can help out.

Some missing elements I feel would be helpful:

- Sample HTML implementation
- Corresponding JS for the html

So we're left with making assumptions, which may or may not help you out.

Can you provide what lightbox plugin you're working with?  Usually though, one defines a div with some content related to what's in the lightbox and then jquery converts that element into the corresponding lightbox.  Within that you would have html for your links.

With jquery using the selectors you have given, you'd do something like:

```
jQuery('#nextLink').attr('href', '<new url>');  // Replacing <new url> with the new value of course.
jQuery('#nextLink').attr('href', '<new url>');
```

A very assumptive jsfiddle implementation can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/WATg6/6/